# Java string recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to learn Java, and now I'm trying algorithms. So, I'm stucked on recursion. I have a code that I don't understand.

```
public static String reverseString(String text){
  
// base case
  
if (text.length() == 0) {
    return text;
  } 

else {

    // recursive call

    return reverseString(text.substring(1)) + text.charAt(0);
  }
}
 
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = new String("howdy");
  // calling recursive function
  String reverse = reverseString(str);
  System.out.println(reverse); // Prints: ydwoh
}
```

Problem is that for me recursive call in this code for me is:

for the first time it retuns *owdyh*,

second time *wdyo* and so on.

I can't understand how the string *ydwoh* borns. I suspect that somewhere chars concotanating in the right order, and stored somewhere, but where is this place I also don't know.

**UPDATE**

I tried it with paper, what I got:

first recursive call:

return value owdyh = "owdy" + "h"

second call:

return value wdyo = "wdy" + "o"

and so on

Comment: I suggest getting a pen and paper and tracing out what steps the input 'howdy' goes through. That way, you can see and understand what exactly is happening in the call stack.

Comment: it worked fine for me. But if you want to understand recursion you better trace it on a paper like @Tim said.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty is the processing *after* the call. The first letter is added to the end of the result of `reverseString` of the rest.

```
reverseString "howdy"
  reverseString "owdy"
    reverseString "wdy"
      reverseString "dy"
        reverseString "y"
          reverseString ""
            return ""
          return "" + "y"
        returns "y" + "d"
      returns "yd" + "w"
    returns "ydw" + "o"
  returns "ydwo" + "h"
returns "ydwoh"
```

It is like a mathematical proof by induction:

- The empty string is reversed (result empty string).
- When the recursive call works on a smaller string,
  placing the first char at the end, also reverses the string.
- So `reverseString` works for all length of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! They helped me to figure out my misunderstanding!
What I couldn't understand is *where* all the chars from the `text.charAt(0)` are stored! The trick  is that they are stored in the stack without any links. It's LIFO(Last-In-First-Out) approach in work.